# How to get a password with a CLI program?

Tags: c++, linux, passwords

I am writing a Linux CLI program.  I need to get a password from the user and, obviously, I don't want the password to be echoed to the console.

There are several solutions available here, but they are all for plain C. 
[C command-line password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786532/c-command-line-password-input)
[How to mask password in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754004/how-to-mask-password-in-c)
[Getting a password in C without using getpass (3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196418/getting-a-password-in-c-without-using-getpass-3)

How can those be adapted for C++, using std::string instead of char[]?

What would be the most elegant C++ solution?

Comment: If you have a `char x[]`, you can create `std::string s(x);`.

Comment: If you care about security, then don't use `std::string`, use a plain old `char` buffer in an `mlock`'d region to avoid the password being copied all over memory and ending up in the swap file. Erase it with `memset` as soon as you're done with it.

Comment: @Tony: thanks. I'm still struggling with the basics, so I don't yet think about simple things like this.

Comment: @larsmans: thanks. I do care about security and study about it a bit every day. Your advice is useful. +1 as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a password from std::cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of the plain C solutions:

```
std::string pass (100);  // size the string at your max password size (minus one)

func_to_get_pass(&pass[0], pass.size());
// function takes a char* and the max size to write (including a null char)

pass.resize(pass.find('\0'));

cout << "Your password is " << pass << ".\n"; // oops! don't show it ;)
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for the code. I don't master this kind of simple things, yet. It's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Linux itself is written (mostly) in C, so anything you could find in C++ would only be an abstraction around a single C routine. Better to call the routine yourself, converting the input and result.